# App Store Information items in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

My app keeps rejecting since month they review more then 2 week and reject it now rejected due to this issue i have places all the information already
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1U0u.jpg

> Guideline 3.1.2 - Business - Payments - Subscriptions
>
> We also still noticed that your app's metadata did not fully meet the terms and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in Schedule 2, section 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement.
>
> App Store Information
>
> We were unable to find the following App Store Information items in App Store Connect.
>
> – Information about the auto-renewable nature of the subscription in your app's description:
>
> • Title of publication or service
> • Length of subscription (time period and content or services provided during each subscription period)
> • Payment will be charged to iTunes Account at confirmation of purchase
> • Subscription automatically renews unless auto-renew is turned off at least 24-hours before the end of the current period
> • Account will be charged for renewal within 24-hours prior to the end of the current period, and identify the cost of the renewal
> • Subscriptions may be managed by the user and auto-renewal may be turned off by going to the user's Account Settings after purchase
> • Any unused portion of a free trial period, if offered, will be forfeited when the user purchases a subscription to that publication, where applicable
> – A link to the terms of use in either the app description or EULA field
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app's metadata to include this missing information. If the above information is in your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide details on where to locate it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions related to app stores are off-topic. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic for further details

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a disclosure in your application or into the description that **prevent the user about the subscription**.

You can find below a template you need to add.

> A [purchase amount and period] purchase will be applied to your iTunes
>   account [at the end of the trial or intro| on confirmation].
>
> Subscriptions will automatically renew unless canceled within 24-hours
>   before the end of the current period. You can cancel anytime with your
>   iTunes account settings. Any unused portion of a free trial will be
>   forfeited if you purchase a subscription.
>
> For more information, see our [link to ToS] and [link to Privacy
>   Policy].

Reference to this template: [Template](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/apple-will-reject-your-subscription-app-if-you-dont-include-this-disclosure-bba95244405d)

Comment: i have added already this in app in the page of the subscription check  https://imgur.com/a/5PXM83w

Comment: they want to add me information in  App Store Connect i don't know where they want please guide me

Comment: You need to add the same information to your App Store Description as well as in the app.